# Github 304 responses seem to count against rate limit

Tags: github-api, rate-limiting

I'm running into an issue with the github api counting requests that yeild a 304 response against the rate limit

```
GET /repos/******/***/contents/***?ref=master HTTP/1.1
Host: api.github.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
If-None-Match: W/"b15846765021dc2483e5f3110b53a69f210ececa"
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 01:33:51 GMT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Origin: *******
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: ******
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

this request will return with a 304 and no body, but X-Ratelimit-Remaining decrements.

[Conditional Github Requests](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#conditional-requests)

> Note: Making a conditional request and receiving a 304 response does not count against your Rate Limit, so we encourage you to use it whenever possible.

I'm only setting the If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since  headers, the rest are set by the browser (using fetch api)

### Request

This can be replicated with just a browser by navigating to `https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/contents/?ref=master` and making sure disable cache is off in the developer console

### Responses

#### On first call

`If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` are not set

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 12:43:09 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
server: GitHub.com
status: 200 OK
cache-control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
etag: W/"b15846765021dc2483e5f3110b53a69f210ececa"
last-modified: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 01:33:51 GMT
x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
access-control-expose-headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
access-control-allow-origin: *
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
x-frame-options: deny
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
content-encoding: gzip
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 60
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 59
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1585748589
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1696
X-GitHub-Request-Id: B298:74D9:10D7B8:177665:5E848C5D
```

followed by the requested data

#### Subsequent Calls:

`If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` are set to `etag` and `last-modified` header from previous request

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
date: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 12:44:51 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
server: GitHub.com
status: 200 OK
cache-control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
etag: W/"b15846765021dc2483e5f3110b53a69f210ececa"
last-modified: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 01:33:51 GMT
x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
access-control-expose-headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
access-control-allow-origin: *
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
x-frame-options: deny
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
content-encoding: gzip
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 60
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 58
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1585748589
X-GitHub-Request-Id: FC10:2036:26E528:346432:5E848CC3
```

no data is returned.
According to the documentation `X-Ratelimit-Remaining` should have stayed at 59

Is there something wrong with my request or is there a bug with the ratelimit on githubs end?

Comment: Can you share the response headers you are seeing? There might be some detail in there that would help understand the behaviour better. Also, maybe stripping out some unnecessary headers here to just the essential ones here might help.

Comment: edited to show a full example. as far as i'm aware the only essential headers are `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since`

Comment: It's worth checking that there aren't any redirects involved. Even if the ultimate response is a 304, requesting a repository that has been renamed using its old name will still count against your rate limit.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the documentation `X-Ratelimit-Remaining` should have stayed at 59

This `59` here suggests that you're performing unauthenticated requests, which might be key here. I wonder if this is related to the rate limits for unauthenticated requests not being measured in the same way as authenticated requests, and this situation may not be considered a "conditional" request.

This case is not documented explicitly, but GitHub highly recommends using authenticated requests as these rate limits are tracked per-account, not per-IP address.

Comment: You are correct the request are unauthenticated. It could well be that the conditional requests don't work without auth. Can't find that documented anywhere though

Answer (score 1):

got the same problem. and resolved it. i've added to headers 'Authorization' key with string value. i'm using python and requests for humans. so in my console looks this like that:

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://api.github.com/repos/zappycode/zappycode-django/commits', headers={'Authorization': 'JustaString', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0', 'If-Modified-Since': 'Sat, 18 Jul 2020 00:15:14 GMT'})
>>> response.headers
{'Date': 'Tue, 21 Jul 2020 09:06:05 GMT', 'Server': 'GitHub.com', 'Status': '304 Not Modified', 'X-RateLimit-Limit': '60', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining': '59', 'X-RateLimit-Reset': '1595323695', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60', 'Vary': 'Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With, Accept-Encoding', 'ETag': '"03e2ffed23748e4e7fee925076e63b47"', 'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 18 Jul 2020 00:15:14 GMT', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Referrer-Policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'none'", 'X-GitHub-Request-Id': 'B6AC:EC41:82A5D:B3030:5F16AFFD'}
>>> response_2 = requests.get('http://api.github.com/repos/zappycode/zappycode-django/commits', headers={'Authorization': 'JustaString', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0', 'If-Modified-Since': 'Sat, 18 Jul 2020 00:15:14 GMT'})
>>> response_2.headers
{'Date': 'Tue, 21 Jul 2020 09:06:44 GMT', 'Server': 'GitHub.com', 'Status': '304 Not Modified', 'X-RateLimit-Limit': '60', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining': '59', 'X-RateLimit-Reset': '1595323695', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60', 'Vary': 'Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With, Accept-Encoding', 'ETag': '"03e2ffed23748e4e7fee925076e63b47"', 'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 18 Jul 2020 00:15:14 GMT', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Referrer-Policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'none'", 'X-GitHub-Request-Id': 'A962:EC4D:11CCB9AF:15D06EA5:5F16B023'}
>>> response_3 = requests.get('http://api.github.com/repos/zappycode/zappycode-django/commits', headers={'Authorization': 'JustaString', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0', 'If-Modified-Since': 'Sat, 18 Jul 2020 00:15:14 GMT'})
>>> response_3.headers
{'Date': 'Tue, 21 Jul 2020 09:07:39 GMT', 'Server': 'GitHub.com', 'Status': '304 Not Modified', 'X-RateLimit-Limit': '60', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining': '59', 'X-RateLimit-Reset': '1595323695', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60', 'Vary': 'Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With, Accept-Encoding', 'ETag': '"03e2ffed23748e4e7fee925076e63b47"', 'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 18 Jul 2020 00:15:14 GMT', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Referrer-Policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'none'", 'X-GitHub-Request-Id': 'A968:69B0:11A84908:159BBA46:5F16B05B'}
```

hope it's gonna work for u :)

Comment: I can't comment on whether this worked at the time of posting but I just tried it and its not working for me now.